# How can I check if two Java classes are semantically identical?

Tags: java, merge, versioning

I need to merge two similar huge projects (1000+ classes). The second one is a fork of the first one, and it contains some country-specific behavior. The two projects diverge a lot, because svn versioning was handled very poorly.

It often happens that two classes are semantically identical. Their source codes only differ in terms of warnings, import statements, the order of some methods or variables, code formatting, comments, etc.

Is there a way to automatically check if two classes are semantically identical?

Comment: Reflection: `getFields` and `getMethods`

Comment: Check the bytecode, i.e. read the `.class` files using some bytecode library and compare them. If the bytecode is equivalent, the classes are "semantically identical".

Comment: Git difff?? ........

Comment: @SamOrozco That's not sufficient--you could have the same methods, but implementations that do different things.

Comment: Git diff won't recognize methods/variables placed in very different positions. getFields and getMethods only check for signatures, not for identical method implementations.

Comment: I would parse Java files from these projects pairwise and compare ASTs according to the rules you've defined. Then check the comparison results, tune the rules, repeat. But it can be pretty hard.

Comment: @agdev84, Program analysis will be very handy for you. For example, you can compare the CFGs to find equivalency of two methods. You will have full control on what you want to compare or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider using program analysis tools like [Soot](https://github.com/Sable/soot/wiki/Tutorials). Soot has some excellent APIs to analyze code that is best suited for your purpose. For example, to check whether two classes "semantically identical", you can consider (1) whether both of the classes have same (or similar fields) (2) both of the classes has same (or similar methods).

Fields are represented as [`SootField`](https://www.sable.mcgill.ca/soot/doc/soot/SootField.html) in Soot. You will have all the necessary information in a `SootField` object that you want to use for comparison. To check the semantic similarity of two methods you can check whether their control flow graphs ([CFGs](https://www.sable.mcgill.ca/soot/doc/soot/toolkits/graph/UnitGraph.html)) are similar or not (Details are in Section 5.7 of [this guide](http://www.brics.dk/SootGuide/sootsurvivorsguide.pdf)).

> Tips on how you can use soot.

If your source dir is `srcDir`, Java Home is `javaHome` and the list of classes is `classNames`, then you can use the following code snippet to programmatically load your classes in Soot toolset.

```
 String sootClassPath = srcDir + ":" 
            + javaHome + "/jre/lib/rt.jar:"
            +javaHome + "/jre/lib/jce.jar";

    Options.v().set_output_format(Options.output_format_jimple);
    Options.v().set_src_prec(Options.src_prec_java);

    for (String className : classNames) { // // "className" is like a.b.Myclass
        Options.v().classes().add(className);
    }

    Options.v().set_keep_line_number(true);
    Options.v().set_allow_phantom_refs(true);
    Scene.v().setSootClassPath(sootClassPath);

    Scene.v().loadBasicClasses();
```

When your classes are loaded, you can access a class like below:

```
 SootClass sClass = Scene.v().loadClassAndSupport(className); // "className" is like a.b.Myclass
```

Now you can access the fields and methods of `sClass` like below:

```
 Chain<SootField> fieldList =  sClass.getFields(); // import soot.util.Chain;
 List<SootMethod> methods = sClass.getMethods();
```

You can iterate the CFG of a method, like below to get the list of instructions of it,

```
  if (method.isConcrete()) {

     List<Unit> instructionList = new ArrayList<>();

     Body b = method.retrieveActiveBody();
     DirectedGraph g = new ExceptionalUnitGraph(b);
     Iterator gitr = g.iterator();
     while (gitr.hasNext()) {
          Unit unit = (Unit) gitr.next();
          instructionList.add(unit);
     }
  }
```

Comment: Very interesting library and solution. I will test it as soon as possible. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe first convert 2 projects' code into UML diagrams using a tool like [Architexa](http://www.architexa.com/support/videos/intro/video).
This may help identify the real function of classes in the context of the system objective.
Suspected equivalent classes can then be compared in detail.